# Remove overlay window from the ballon in android

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, balloon

I want to hide the overlay item window popup after click on the mapview. Currently when i click on the balloon then popup window comes. if i tap on other ballon then previous ballon pop up window hide and new pop up window comes on that ballon. this is correct. But I have a problem to hide that pop up on the mapview click/Touch. Please share the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To resolve this firstly you have to take static variable in the MapActivity.

e.g public static isMapRefreshed = false;

Then goto BalloonItemizedOverlay class there is a draw method there.
write following code there to resolve this.

private BalloonOverlayView balloonView;

if(UsersNearMe.isMapRefreshed){
     hideBalloon();
}

private void hideBalloon() {
    if (balloonView != null) {
        balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

on mapview clicklistener change the static value for the isMapRefreshed to true. and on tap change the static value for the isMapRefreshed to false